# How to keep the log files of a pod in the node after the pod is deleted or evicted?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-pod

We plan to collect application logs at the node level. Specifically, use a log collector, e.g. `filebeat`, to collect logs from `/var/log/pods/` from each node (basically the [node-logging-agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-node-logging-agent) way in the official doc of kubernetes).

When a pod get deleted (e.g. due to a rolling update) or get evicted from the node somehow, we still want to collect up all the logs produced by the pod. But this requirement is not readily met in the [node-logging-agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-node-logging-agent) way, because the log files of the pod will be deleted from the node immediately when the pod is deleted or evicted.

Is there a way to let kubernetes keep the log files of a deleted or evicted pod in the node, maybe with a specified TTL?

Comment: If you dont want the files to be deleted, you can mount a Persistence Volume Claim in your pod and store the logs in there. And you can have your log collector mount the same volume and process the logs.

Comment: @Bala Yes, but in that way each container has to log to a designated path and manage the log file rotation, which is less convenient. And still, some error message and logs from third-party library will go to stdout/stderr. So the problem is still there.

Comment: @updogliu what about the sidecar approaches presented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-logging-agent?